# Listing unwanted files recursively in a directory - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a Powershell script that will display a list of files and folders in a directory('s) while not displaying a specific folder and a file.

I have a bunch of directories on the C:\ that have a folder "DATA" and a "Setup.ini" file within them.
Every once in a while people go into the data folder and make copies and then place those copies of files and directories right inside of the main directory with the "DATA" and ".ini" files.
Then at the end of each month, I normally need to go through each of these directories and delete anything that is not the "DATA" folder and ".ini" file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\TestDir" -Exclude 'Setup.ini' |  Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch 'Data'}
```

This seems to sort of work and is what I have been using this month.
It runs really slow. I also noticed that one of the Directories had 2 extra folders and a zip file within it.
The script only showed one of the folders and didn't show the zip file either.

I have tried adding other things to this code, but when I do that it begins showing me data inside of the "DATA" folder which I don't want.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong or ways to make this run quicker?
I think it is taking about 7-10mins to run through 113 directories.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say _"place those copies of files and directories right inside of the main directory"_ you mean `C:\DATA\DATA(this is the copied folder)` or `C:\Copy of DATA`?

Comment: Sorry, when I say make a copy and place it inside of the main directory I mean it would be something like c:\testdir\data and also c:\testdir\data - copy

Answer (score 1):

Expand the -Exclude and drop the Where-Object:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\TestDir" -Exclude 'Setup.ini','Data'
```

HTH

Comment: I did try this version of the code yesterday. While it does work it searches/lists files and subdirectories inside of the Data folder which I don't want to see.
The tree looks like this:
C:\
C:\TestDir
C:\TestDir\P1
C:\TestDir\P1\Data
--
Then there is also:
C:\TestDir\P2
C:\TestDir\P2\Data

It goes on like this about 113 times. In the P1/P2/etc.etc folders are Data and the ini file.
I am just looking for the script to show me any extra files or folders in the P1/P2 folders that are not the Data folder or the INI file.

Comment: Chuck, theoretically this should work! However, a search shows that the -Exclude parameter is seriously broken and my further testing bears this out. Looks like you'll have to look for efficiencies elsewhere.